# Dealing with Multiple User Roles

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a project based on a CMS, where there is a built-in roles table.

However, the CMS allows a user to have one role only using `role_id`

And these are the requirements that struggling me:

- A user can be a Freelancer and an Employer at the same time.
- A user has a Freelancer Feedback and an Employer Feedback.

This is what I came up:

```
Users
id | role_id  | freelancer  | employer |  freelancer_feedback  | employer_feedback
```

freelancer, and employer will have an `active` or  `inactive` values.

And we will use the role_id for authorization purposes (if user is a user or moderator or developer, etc) only

```
Roles
role_id  | role_name  |  description | login_destination | deleted |  default_context
```

The thing is, I've never dealt with multi roles feature in a project before. I would love to hear from you, tips or suggestions.

Comment: You can see this blog for reff: http://goo.gl/ATnj6j